# Is it natural to say "It was a scare"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrases, idiomatic-language

(Said about a suicide attempt)

***Luckily nothing happened, but it was a scare.***

Is it natural to use "scare" as shown above? Is it formal/informal? Is it used in both North America and the UK? Is there another word that would be more natural to use here than "scare"? Thank you.

Comment: In your sentence you do not relate scare to anything, therefore it cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing things up a little in your use of scare, are you trying to use it as a verb or noun ?

Try modifying your sentence....then select what you are trying to express.

---

**"She threatened to kill herself, luckily nothing happened, but it scared me"**. (= made me extremely frightened)

**scare**; **verb**; to (make a person or animal) feel frightened:

He scared me out of my wits (= made me extremely frightened) by driving so fast.

Meeting new people scares me stiff/to death (= makes me extremely nervous and worried).

She scared the hell/life/living daylights out of me (= frightened me very much) when she fell out of the tree.

---

**You gave us a real scare,** when you threatened to kill yourself. (= frightened us)

**scare: noun**: a sudden feeling of fear or worry:
I got/had a scare (= I was very worried) when I looked at my bank statement this morning!
You gave us a real scare (= frightened us) when you fainted, you know.

Ref CED [Scare](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scare)